Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS update broke nvidia-470 driver
I recently noticed the resolution on my laptop is off and tried to modify it only to realise that something related to the nvidia-470 driver is broken. I've been running around for a solution, but didn't get it to work.
If I run  sudo apt upgrade  I get the following:
Setting up nvidia-dkms-470 (470.256.02-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/quirks-handler", line 26, in <module>
    import Quirks.quirkapplier
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Quirks/quirkapplier.py", line 26, in <module>
    import xkit.xutils
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xkit'
dpkg: error processing package nvidia-dkms-470 (--configure):
 installed nvidia-dkms-470 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-470:
 nvidia-driver-470 depends on nvidia-dkms-470 (<= 470.256.02-1); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-470 is not configured yet.
 nvidia-driver-470 depends on nvidia-dkms-470 (>= 470.256.02); however:
  Package nvidia-dkms-470 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-470 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up python3-update-manager (1:22.04.21) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                       Setting up update-manager-core (1:22.04.21) ...
Setting up update-manager (1:22.04.21) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.6+22.04.20220217-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.72.4-0ubuntu2.3) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.72.4-0ubuntu2.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-122-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-470
 nvidia-driver-470
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


Then I tried installing xkit with: sudo apt install python3-xkit to get the same thing:

did you solve it please

Yes!
dpkg -S `which quirks-handler```` showed the issue was in the ubuntu-drivers-common for me.  So I did apt purge ubuntu-drivers-commonthenapt update
apt autoremove --purge
apt-clean```
Now everything is good again. Hope this helps
